# To <p> or not to <p>?

Tags: html

I recently had a debate with a colleague who claimed that a `<div>` tag should be used over a `<p>` tag when formatting paragraphs.

The case against the use of `<p>` is that it produces irregular spacing across browsers and it is likely to become obsolete like the `<b>` tag.

Is this opinion of the `<p>` tag shared by the community?

Comment: Just to point out, `<b>` (and `<i>` for that matter) are far from obsolete. Check the HTML5 spec.

Comment: Good point - I just checked, I've always been instructed that <b> and <i> are depreciated tags and <strong> and <em> should be used.

Comment: `<strong>` and `<em>` should always be used for emphasis. `<b>` and `<i>` are deprecated in that respect but they do have legitimate, albeit limited, use in HTML5.

Comment: Does this discussion really belong here? It seems to me that this should be on Doctype

Comment: @Charles - it's a grey area at the moment, as the site is still in its infancy. If you feel strongly, feel free to start a new discussion over at http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com - or post your comments here: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117/what-is-the-line-between-a-pro-webmaster-question-and-a-well-not-pro-webmas

Comment: @Farseeker, I'm just basing it on what is in the FAQ; isn't the FAQ supposed to represent what the site's about (even if it is still growing and learning)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`div`s and `p`s are for completely different purposes. `p` is for paragraphs, `div` is for sectional divisions. One is for text formatting, the other is for page structure. It is semantically incorrect to use `div` in place of `p`.

And the reason the use of `b` is discouraged is because it's a presentation tag. It has no semantic meaning. Both `p` and `div` have their own unique semantic meanings. `p` will never be obsolete as long as people still format text into paragraphs.

Your colleague doesn't appear to be familiar with the principle of [separation of content and presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_content_and_presentation). Otherwise, he would know why `b` is abhorred and that presentation issues like text spacing ought to be defined in CSS, not your HTML.

Comment: +1 Agree. Just to emphasise... any "irregular spacing across browsers" (although that is debatable) can be controlled entirely by CSS.

Comment: Yep... `p { margin: 1em 0 }` makes this entire question moot.

Comment: `<b>` does have a semantic meaning now: "The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood, such as key words in a document abstract, product names in a review, actionable words in interactive text-driven software, or an article lede." ([source](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-b-element.html#the-b-element))

Answer (score 13):

`<p>` and `<div>` are not meant for the same purpose, as they have a different semantical meaning:

- `<p>` is for paragraph,
- `<div>` is to "offer a generic
  mechanism for adding structure to
  documents", as stated in the [div
  HTML spec from W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-DIV)

`<p>` may not be deprecated in the future as it still is present in XHTML and HTML 5.

Both tags have different graphical rendering. A `<p>` has a top and a bottom margin of 1em, whereas a `<div>` has no margin at all. But this point is secondary as it may be overridden by CSS.

Also, note this difference: while both tags are of type "block", only `<div>` can contain other block elements. Thus:

- `<p><p> bla </p></p>` is wrong, while
- `<div><div> bla </div></div>` is ok

The important point to remember is both are valid and used tags, but not for the same purpose.